# App Crashing on launch with AppDelegate tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uitableview

I have a `Search Display Controller` which displays the search results in a tableView and another `tableView` made using IB in the same `UIViewController`. The app worked fine until I added the code to populate the tableView I made using IB. But now when the app is launched, it is crashing by showing the following error:

```
'-[VBSAppDelegate tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xae18480'
```

Following code is used to set the number of sections and number of rows in sections(yes, the very normal code)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag == 100) {
        return 60;
    }
    else {
        return [filteredList count];
    }    
}
```

I have set two break points and discovered that for the tableView of search display controller it is getting into `numberOfRowsInSection` and then getting terminated without even entering the `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method. Any idea why this is happening? does it have anything to do with the second tableView? How to rectify this? Please ask if any further code is required. I am developing for iPad.

Comment: Did you use this table view delegate methods or tableview in appdelegate class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by disconnecting the `delegate` and `datasource` connections of the tableView I put in the `xib` via IB, and then I connected is programmatically. It seems the problem was two `delegate` and `datasource`connected via IB causing confusion or something. Hope this helps someone who may be facing a similar issue. Just disconnect the `delegate` and `datasource` of the tableView that you inserted from IB and give it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the connections in your NIB file to specify delegate and data source?